# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, функции, классы

Хочу проверить схожесть паролей первого и второго, вылазит ошибка `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, помогите пожалуйста.

```py
class Register():
    def __init__(self, login, password, password2):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.password2 = password2

    def password(self):
        if 6 < len(self.login) > 15:
            print("Форма вашего логина не должна превышать 15 символов")
        elif self.password != self.password2:
            print("Пароли не совпадают")


car = Register(login="bayaman210234242csdcsdcscdsdcscsccsdcscscdsdcs43231@gmail.com", password=12345678, password2=123456789)
car.password()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProject/register/register.py", line 18, in <module>
    car.password()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Не связано с проблемой, но условие `6 < len(self.login) > 15` означает, что `len(self.login)` должен быть больше 6 и больше 15, т.е. всегда больше 15 - хоть 100 символов, хоть 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы дважды объявляете объекты с одним и тес же именем

```
self.password = password
def password(self):
```

переименуйте функцию, и все заработат

Comment: Спасибо у меня заработало!

Comment: Дополнение - для понятности лучше использовать в имени функции, производящей некие действия, какой-то глагол. В данном случае видимо лучше было бы назвать функцию `check_password`. А так могло быть `get_password`, `set_password` и т.д.